# How to detect Unfinished transaction in sk payment

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am working in Inapp purchase and into my app i want to detect UnFinished or not downloaded product transaction So can i clear them and tell user to download it.

i have tried to detect pending transaction by this way but it fails.

```
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
 NSArray *pendingarray= [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions];
 if(pendingarray.count>0)
 {
   NSLog(@"Pending array count is %d",[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions].count);
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] cancelDownloads:pendingarray];
   }
```

I want to clear all previous transaction from Queue.how can i do that. in my case if my app crash before download finish than next time when you try to buy same product than it start download and verification of receipt automatically So how can i clear unFinished Product queue from SKpayment Observer.
Any help is appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: +1. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506026-transactions) that say that `transactions` will be undefined if no observer is present. Maybe that was the problem?

Comment: @ispiro thank you for response, But in 2013 this document was not updated and we had so much problem to understand the in-app purchase API, But now in 2020 it's very easy task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to finish all transactions in queue, check this: [How to remove a very old, defunct in-app purchase from the transaction queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210747/how-to-remove-a-very-old-defunct-in-app-purchase-from-the-transaction-queue/18219798#18219798)

If that was all what you want, you suggest you to search better next time.

P.S.: You had crash because you were trying to use `-cancelDownloads:` with an array of `SKPaymentTransaction` objects, but it expects an array of `SKDownload` objects.