# Getting this message in my console in xcode "Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions"?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

This is the message I get when I press on my restore purchases button. Here is the code I have for restoring the purchases......Can someone tell me if Im doing something wrong. Thank you! BTW If you need more info or code please let me know.

> Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions

```
func RestorePurchases() {
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    } else {
        println("Can't make purchases")
    }
}


   func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    var purchasedItemIDS = []
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "unlockLevelTwo":
            println("restoreleveltwo")
            unlockLevelTwoPlease()
        case "unlockLevelThree":
            println("restorelevelthree")
            unlockLevelThreePlease()
        default:
            println("IAP not setup")

        }

    }

}


   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


    if node.name == "restore" {
        runAction(menuAudioPlayer)
        RestorePurchases()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling `finishTransaction:` with the transaction once it's restored, so it remains in the payment queue.

From [the documentation for this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/finishTransaction:):

> Your application should call this method from a transaction observer that received a notification from the payment queue. Calling `finishTransaction:` on a transaction removes it from the queue. Your application should call `finishTransaction:` only after it has successfully processed the transaction and unlocked the functionality purchased by the user.

Comment: I already have it in my code...I forgot to post it:    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        println("finish trans")
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
    }

Comment: Where should I add the finsihTransaction: @AaronBrager

Comment: @coding22 Where the documentation says: *"after [your application] has successfully processed the transaction and unlocked the functionality purchased by the user"*

Comment: I did that I still get that message.

Comment: Then you still have unfinished transactions in your queue. Try [clearing them out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18219798/1445366).

Comment: Do you know how to convert that into swift?

Comment: @coding22 Yes, but I recommend you attempt it first on your own (you'll learn more that way).

Comment: I know but im so close to finishing this in app purchase Im stuck on this part now.

Comment: Could I just use a different sandbox account when I press on the restore purchases button? When I press on the button it asks me for my password for my test accounts but then nothing happens.

Comment: I got it to work but it crashes when I press on one of the levels that got unlocked. In the console it says false when I do that. @aaronbrager